# codeigniter using Ignited-Datatables class stuck with joins

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am using this library in codeigniter

```
https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables/blob/master/application/libraries/Datatables.php
```

and having a problem with inner join infact none of the joins are working for me.

```
$this->load->library('datatables');
   $this->datatables
        ->select("id, date, customer_name, inv_total, total_tax, total_discount, 
                total, paid_by, cf1, cf2")
        ->from('sales')
        ->join('customers', 'customers.id=sales.customer_id', 'INNER')
        ->unset_column('id');
         echo $this->datatables->generate();
```

cf1 and cf2 are in customers table i want to retrieve those

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: no error, its no showing anything

Comment: You mean you aren't actually capturing an error? Are you debugging it at all?

Comment: tried to look to error but its not showing anything , simply displaying my page with missing data, it seems like the query error cause it work fine without using joins

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using inner join, and both tables contains field named id, mysql returns error for field ambiguity. So you should reference such fields by tablename.feildname.

```
 $this->datatables
        ->select("sales.id, date, customer_name, inv_total, total_tax, total_discount, 
                total, paid_by, cf1, cf2")
        ->from('sales')
        ->join('customers', 'customers.id=sales.customer_id', 'INNER')
        ->unset_column('sales.id');
         echo $this->datatables->generate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these.

Note: You not included customers table name in select query.

```
$this->load->library('datatables');
$this->datatables
    ->select("id, date, customer_name, inv_total, total_tax, total_discount, total, paid_by, customers.cf1, customers.cf2")
    ->from('sales')
    ->join('customers', 'customers.id=sales.customer_id', 'INNER')
    ->unset_column('id');
     echo $this->datatables->generate();
```